# Использование общего пространства имён Manager - не присваивается список

Tags: python

Не могу изменить вложенный список (=матрицу двумерную) в общем пространстве имён Manager, находясь в процессе (соответственно, и в **main** информация не попадает).
А именно: в примере ниже ns.my_list[1] не принимает значение списка t (я упростил проблему до минимума при отладке, чтобы сюда всё не помещать).
При этом видно в отладочной печати, что ns.my_list[1] – точно список, т.е. по логике, он должен бы принимать значение списка t.
О proxy-objects на python.readthedocs.io внимательно почитал, но не увидел ничего об этом.
Просьба подсказать, в чем причина.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def process_work(ns):
    t = [1,2,3,4]
    ns.my_list[1]=t
    print ('type of ns.my_list[1]:', type(ns.my_list[1])) # <class 'list'>
    print('ns.my_list[1]', ns.my_list[1])                 #ns.my_list[1] [0, 0, 0, 0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mgr=Manager()
    namespace=mgr.Namespace()
    namespace.my_list=mgr.list()
    namespace.my_list= [[0] * 4] * 3 # матрица 3(l)х4(n)

    new_process = Process(target=process_work, args=(namespace,))
    new_process.start()
    new_process.join()
```

(С простым списком - одномерной матрицей всё работает, через Array тоже всё работает, но хочу иметь возможность многомерные массивы/списки списков возвращать, где каждая строка обрабатывается отдельным процессом. Можно одномерный массив для этого использовать через Array, но не хочу так  ограничивать - однажды урезанного знания не хватит).

Comment: Почитайте про immutable объекты в python

Comment: Спасибо за совет, правда, в результате не вижу, как относится к проблеме. Главы такой нет в документации, так что посмотрел по всей документации поиском по immutable - тоже не нашёл, как это относится к проблеме (пусть и выглядит так). Да и не понимаю почему: 1) список (<class 'list'>!) стал бы immutable; 2) пространство имён, специально предназначенное для более сложных целей, чем Value и Array, стало бы частично immutable. Я что-то упускаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
    namespace.my_list = mgr.list()
    namespace.my_list = [[0] * 4] * 3 # матрица 3(l)х4(n)
```

Так вы заменили `mgr.list()` в поле `namespace.my_list` обычным списком, поэтому ничего и не работает. Нужно использовать `mgr.list()` и тогда всё работает:

```py
    namespace.my_list = mgr.list([[0] * 4] * 3) # матрица 3(l)х4(n)
```

Вывод:

```
type of ns.my_list[1]: <class 'list'>
ns.my_list[1] [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Либо, если вы хотите заполнять этот список постепенно, то делать так:

```py
    namespace.my_list = mgr.list()
    for _ in range(3):
        namespace.my_list.append([0] * 4)
```

Но в любом случае основное тут - чтобы в `namespace.my_list` был обязательно `mgr.list()`. А когда вы присваиваете в `namespace.my_list` результат работы *спискового включения*, то вы заменяете эту переменную и `mgr.list()` там больше нет.

Comment: Большое спасибо, да, всё работает теперь (и на этом, и на "большом" скрипте). Стыдно мне немного, конечно. Моя ошибка тут - сочетание туннельного видения при отладке (зациклен был именно на особенностях процессов и механизмов передачи между ними) + мозг всё ещё неявно опирается на идеи статической типизации из моего любимого С. 
(У вас маленькая описка, вероятно,  - скорее "спискового включения", чем "спискового сокращения"?)

Comment: @Сергей Вы пишите много лишнего в комментариях.

Comment: Спасибо за предупреждение. Могу писать меньше, но разве анализ причин ошибки не поможет другим из сообщества, кто попадет в подобную ситуацию? (вопрос не риторический) Потому и написал это.

Comment: @Сергей Мне кажется, списковое сокращение тоже допустимый термин, но формально да, включение )  А так да, динамическая типизация много подводных камней из себя представляет, на которые напарываются пишущие на питоне

Comment: Просто "списковое сокращение" Google вообще не находит. Предлагает только "списковое включение". А так смысл понятен, спасибо.